# What is expected files size in var/cache/

Tags: cache, magento2.4

Some files in var/cache/ folders are as large as 300Mb is this considered as normal or something is wrong with my Magento? (see screenshot)

Iam running Magento ver. 2.4.0 with up to 2000 products, single customer group.

[image: var/cache/]

Comment: This is exactly our problem and the var/cache folder get's to a size of over 20GB in a matter of hours. I noticed that the file names contain same things as in our case FINAL_PRICE_LIST_CATEGORY_PAGE_GBP. Did you find a solution to this problem? This hangs the server and processes get stuck. The problem goes away for a few hours when you flush the cache. Did you find any permanent solution?

Answer (score 1):

These are page cache files and they can be deleted, it seems your script does not clean up cache files and the size of the files & folder is growing constantly.

If you won't delete, then it will increase upto 400Mb after weeks 500 MB. I Have face the same problem. So it would be better if you can delete your cache file in every week by manually or using script.

And if You know it's completely safe to delete everything under var if you need storage space.

According to you,Your website has 2000 products,So it will always increase 100- 200 mb every week. So you can delete by script on every week.

**Updated Answer**

**Note one more thing,** if you won't delete then after sometime when there is shortage of storage then user won't able to login as session will not be created due to no size left on disk space. And the cart page will not work as well.,

Comment: Iam interested to find out why some files in var/cache/ folders are as large as 300Mb. It does not seem appropirate to me and the server must process these files which mean to me loads of resorces are taken.